# How to fix 'Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format'

Tags: r

I am setting up my variable to hold the filtered dates of when there are suspicious phone calls through the 2007 year. However, something is fishy with setting the Date format in the Date column.

I've tried without format, moving the `%m/%d/%Y` to `%Y/%m/%d`, I've tried switching from `01/01/2007` to `2007/01/01` as well as the `01-01-2007`.

```
SFPD_reports <- read_csv("SFPD_Incident_Reports_2003_May2018.csv")

SetDate_SetCrime <- Create_Fil_Sus %>%
  mutate(Date = format(as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")))

SetDate_SetCrime <-  select(Create_Fil_Sus, IncidntNum, Descript, DayOfWeek, Date, Location)%>%
  filter(Date >= (as.Date("01/01/2006", "%m/%d/%Y") & (Date <= as.Date("12/31/2007", "%m/%d/%Y"),
         Descript == "SUSPICIOUS PERSON"))%>%
  mutate(lat= (str_sub(Location, 26, str_length(Location))),
         lon= (str_sub(Location, 9, 24)))
```

But I get:

> Error in charToDate(x) : 
>     character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Answer (score 0):

```
# SetDate_SetCrime <- Create_Fil_Sus %>%
#   mutate(Date = format(as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")))
Create_Fil_Sus <- mutate(Create_Fil_Sus, Date = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Mutating the same object, produced the correct formate (the uncommented line of code worked). Yippie